# Printing the C file variable if is declared more than once

Tags: python

```
for cVariable in CFile.Variables:
    occCtr=0
    for cVar2 in CFile.Variables:
        if  cVariable.Name == cVar2.Name:
            occCtr+=1
    if occCtr > 1:
        res = False
        errmsg += cVariable.Name + ' is declared more than once ' + '\n'
```

This is my algorithm. It is parsing a C file and finds out if a variable is declared more than once. But when I print the Error Message, it shows me both variables that have the same name and I only need to print one from each of them

Comment: The variable will match against itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

declarations = Counter(var.Name for var in CFile.Variables)
duplicates = [
    "{} is declared {} times".format(name, times)
    for name, times in declarations.items() where times > 1
]
duplicates.sort()
error_msg = "\n".join(duplicates)
```

Comment: It looks like my collections.py is missing. Is there any way to transform this into a loop with conditions ? Thanks for your answer !

Comment: @Alex It would be better if you fixed your installation